# Using two drop downs in .NET to manipulate a third drop down list

Tags: c#, .net

I am programing in .NET using C# and I have 3 drop downs. Depending on the contents of the first two dropdowns determines the value of the 3rd. The user cannot change the 3rd, it is populated automatically. Lets call these Dropdowns A. B and C. If A has any value selected, C gets a value of X automatically. If A is blank and B has any value selected, C gets a value of Y. Now if A gets selected, then B gets selected, C should have a value of X. Thus if A has any value it supersedes what is in B. How do you do this? I have programmed some events but I have no idea how to make it so B needs to check what is checked in for A before determing the value of C. Hope this didn't sound too confusing.

Comment: in winforms, WPF, silverlight or on web?

Comment: You may want to include some sample code of things you have tried before your thread gets killed. In basic logic, though, you probably want one event that is called whenever A or B change and then evaluate your business requirements in that event.

Comment: I already coded some events where the contents of the drop down alter that 3rd field. That I get. I just wanted some basic ideas of how on an event one drop down can check the checked value of another dropdown that's all.

Comment: 1) Set an onchange on A and B to call valueChanged(). 2) In valueChanged(), check if A is filled, if so, set C to X. If A is not filled and B is filled, set C to Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume this is for WinForms since you didn't specify. What you should do is use the `SelectedIndexChanged` event for the comboboxes. Then clear `comboBox3` whenever the user selects something from `comboBox1` or `comboBox2`.

```
this.comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(this.comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);

this.comboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(this.comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged);

// ...

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Choosing an item in comboBox1 will always replace the items in comboBox3
    this.comboBox3.Items.Clear();
    this.comboBox3.Items.Add(X);
}

private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Only fill comboBox3 if the user hasn't chosen an item in comboBox1
    if (this.comboBox1.SelectedItem == null)
    {
        this.comboBox3.Items.Clear();
        this.comboBox3.Items.Add(Y);
    }
}
```

1. When the user chooses something from `comboBox1` and `comboBox2` has not selected value, `comboBox3` will contain X
2. When the user chooses something from `comboBox2` and `comboBox1` has not selected value, `comboBox3` will contain Y
3. When the user chooses something from `comboBox1` and the user has selected something from `comboBox2`, then `comboBox3` will contain X
4. When the user chooses something from `comboBox2` and the user has selected something from `comboBox1`, then `comboBox3` will contain X

Comment: Yup I used something close to what you suggested here and it worked. Thanks a lot man you are a life saver.